# How to get ahead of queue?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make guys stand in line when they try to book tickets on my site, especially when a lot of people are trying at the same time.

I'm wondering (hypothetically) if there's a way for people to skip this queue and get straight to booking?

Here's the code:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
            var time_done = 263;
            var time_retry = 30;
            var time_todo = 7786;
    var todo_pix = 100;
    var done_pix = 0;
    var width = 100;
    var ppu = 0;
    var interval = 0;

    function progress_queue()
    {
        width = document.getElementById('contain').width;
        if(time_done > -1) 
        {
            if(!interval) 
            {
                ppu = width / (time_todo+time_done);
                update_qtime();
            }
            interval = (1000*time_todo)/todo_pix;
            document.getElementById('done').style.width = parseInt(done_pix) + 'px';
            document.getElementById('todo').style.width = parseInt(todo_pix) + 'px';
                document.getElementById('jhide').style.visibility = "visible";
            todo_pix--;
            done_pix++;
            if (time_retry > 3) setTimeout('progress_queue()', interval);
        }
    }

    function update_qtime()
    {
        time_todo--;
        time_done++;
        todo_pix = time_todo*ppu;
        done_pix = time_done*ppu;
        setTimeout('update_qtime()', 1000);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, could you please clarify.

Comment: Well I'm wondering if there's a way for people to exploit this code and simply skip the code? What I want is that people gets lined up to certain events and I wonder if they can get passed the whole idea of the system by skipping the queue.

Answer (score 3):

Things like ticket queues should be done through a server-side language like PHP -- not client-side languages like Javascript.

If I'm reading your code correctly, all they'd need to do would be to either disable Javascript or set a breakpoint in Firebug (or whatever), and then use Firebug/whatever to set the visibility of #done to visible.